# Internet Explorer - setTimeout(fn, 0) vs setTimeout(fn, 1)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asynchronous, settimeout

I'm running into this scenario in Internet Explorer(IE) 10 where in if I have a sequence of some asynchronous code consisting of a Promise and setTimeout functions with a delay of 1 and a delay of 0 ms, the order of execution is setTimeout(0)->resolve->setTimeout(1). According to my understanding, the order of execution should be **resolve**->setTimeout(1)->setTimeout(0).

```js
var getData = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("Promise resolved")
  });
}
getData().then(function(value) {
  console.log(value)
});
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("setTimeout 1")
}, 1);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("setTimeout 0")
}, 0);
```

Any help understanding this behavior would be great.

Comment: Well the `setTimeout()` order you see is correct and I'm not sure how you think the 1ms timer would fire before the 0ms timer. The Promise is a little odd, but Promise resolution is supposed to happen in a "clean stack" context.

Comment: timers dont fire exactly. 10seconds will fire much earlier than 1minute, but the 1millisecond difference may change due to execution delays...

Comment: I've found that browsers are pretty good at firing timer callbacks in their "realistic" order, even when they're actually firing in the same clock frame.